# Had statisticians predicted 2008 financial crisis?

Tags: finance, prediction, copula

Are there any statistical or econometric studies before 2008 that predicted [2008 financial crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007%E2%80%932012_global_financial_crisis)?
Note that there are [some publications](http://maf2012.unive.it/viewpaper.php?id=203) that attemp to predict contagion between markets using copula concept from probability theory.

Comment: Some things are very hard to predict.  This is one of the events that Taleb called "Black Swans" that made his first book that claimed statisticians can't predict financial events a New York Times best seller.  Ability to predict is based on adequacy of the model and available information.  At the time of 9/11/2001 there was intelligence information that al Qaeda was planning a major attack on the US in that time frame.  The same terrorists had bombed the World Trade Center previously. Getting the intelligence information to the analysts and then the decisionmakers is what matters.

Comment: Many statisticians think that even with limited test data the risk of O-ring failure at low temperature could be determined to be too high to risk on a cold weather launch of Challenger.  This is an issue of sharing good information and weighing the risk benifits and not one where copulas are going to somehow be the magic answer.

Comment: [This paper (pdf)](http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/15892/1/MPRA_paper_15892.pdf) may be useful. Steve Keen is credited with predicting the crisis, applying data to a model he developed in the 1990s. However if I recall correctly he got the date wrong by a year or two. [Quite a few people](http://www.investorhome.com/predicted.htm) predicted a crisis but the hard part is to decide which were just lucky guesses. Mostly the predictions rely on economic models and theory more than statistical analysis (though they at least had an eye on the data).